# Qiskit No backend matches the criteria

Tags: qiskit

I am trying to run a circuit with 32 qubit on a local hpc (not IBM Q HPC) using `statevector_simulator` backend.

but i got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testQiskit11.py", line 156, in <module>
    backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator', max_memory_mb=65536)
  File "/home/UserName/.conda/envs/quantum/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/aer/aerprovider.py", line 37, in get_backend
    return super().get_backend(name=name, **kwargs)
  File "/home/UserName/.conda/envs/quantum/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/baseprovider.py", line 53, in get_backend
    raise QiskitBackendNotFoundError('No backend matches the criteria')
qiskit.providers.exceptions.QiskitBackendNotFoundError: 'No backend matches the criteria'
```

The part of the script that specify the backend and run the simulation is as follow:

```
backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator', max_memory_mb=65536)
backend.MAX_QUBIT_MEMORY=32
shots = 1024
job = execute(QCirc, backend)
result = job.result()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read this tutorial to see how backend filtering works: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/basics/2_the_ibmq_provider.ipynb

Also, Aer is a local simulator, so the amount of memory available is determined by the computer you are running it on.  Setting `MAX_QUBIT_MEMORY` manually will do nothing but cause your computer to freeze if you do not have enough memory to support 32 qubits.

Comment: My job runs locally on an HPC not related to IBM Q. How to calculate the required amount of memory for simulating 32 qubit. According to [this](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/blob/master/qiskit/providers/aer/backends/qasm_simulator.py) the calculation is as follow: 
`MAX_QUBIT_MEMORY = int(
        log2(local_hardware_info()['memory'] * (1024**3) / 16)) ` which get the the number of qubits based on the the memory size and that each element in the state vector requires 16 bytes. And i set `max_memory_mb=65536` which is the exact amount of memory required for 32 qubit state vector.

Comment: You cannot set max memory